# What is the best way to use agricolae to do ANOVAs on a split plot design?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run some ANOVAs on data from a split plot experiment, ideally using the `agricolae` package. It's been a while since I've taken a stats class and I wanted to be sure I'm analyzing this data correctly, so I did some searching online and couldn't really find consistency in the way people were analyzing their split plot experiments. What is the best way for me to do this?

Here's the head of my data:

```
dput(head(rawData))
structure(list(ï..Plot = 2111:2116, Variety = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Burbank", "Hodag", "Lamoka", 
"Norkotah", "Silverton", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), Rate = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Rep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), totalTubers = c(594L, 
605L, 656L, 729L, 694L, 548L), totalOzNoCulls = c(2544.18, 2382.07, 
2140.69, 2401.56, 2440.56, 2503.5), totalCWTacNoCulls = c(461.76867, 
432.345705, 388.535235, 435.88314, 442.96164, 454.38525), avgLWratio = c(1.260615419, 
1.287949374, 1.111981583, 1.08647584, 1.350686661, 1.107173509
), Hollow = c(14L, 15L, 22L, 25L, 14L, 13L), Double = c(10L, 
13L, 15L, 22L, 11L, 9L), Knob = c(86L, 80L, 139L, 156L, 77L, 
126L), Researcher = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Wang", class = "factor"), 
    CullsPounds = c(1.75, 1.15, 4.7, 1.85, 0.8, 5.55), CullsOz = c(28, 
    18.4, 75.2, 29.6, 12.8, 88.8), totalOz = c(2572.18, 2400.47, 
    2215.89, 2431.16, 2453.36, 2592.3), totalCWTacCulls = c(466.85067, 
    435.685305, 402.184035, 441.25554, 445.28484, 470.50245)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

For these data, the whole plot is `Rate`, the split plot is `Variety`, the block is `Rep`, and for discussion's sake here, we can look at `totalCWTacNoCulls` as the response.

Any help would be very much appreciated! I am still getting the hang of Stack Overflow, so if I have made any mistakes or shared my data wrong, please let me know and I'll change it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `agricolae` package as follows

```
library(agricolae)
attach(rawData)
Rate = factor(Rate)
Variety = factor(Variety)
Rep = factor(Rep)
sp.plot(Rep, Rate, Variety, totalCWTacNoCulls)
```

Usage according to `agricolae` package is

```
sp.plot(block, pplot, splot, Y)
```

where, block is replications, pplot is main-plot Factor, splot is sub-plot Factor and Y response variable